# Accessing BOOL within blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to set a flag using a `BOOL` within a block.

I declare the `BOOL` like this:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL flag;
```

And within the block:

```
__strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
if(strongSelf->_flag)
```

My question is, if I do:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
if(weakSelf->_flag)
```

I would get an error:

> "dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed die to possible null
>   value caused by a race condition, assign it to strong variable first"

Can someone explain to me what this means?

In addition, it seems funny to me I have to reference the `BOOL` using `__strong` 
(i.e. `strongSelf->_flag`), would that be the same as using `self->_flag`, because I would be using a strong self here?

---

More over, if I declare the `BOOL` as an ivar instead of a property:

```
BOOL flag;
```

It would give me a warning also when I use it within the block:

```
if(flag)
```

And so I would need to do the following as well:

```
__strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
if(strongSelf->flag)
```

This baffles me, because normally we reference an ivar without `self`, just `flag`, but the above case seems to me that it is accessing the ivar like `self->_flag`.

??

I could have use something else such as a `NSNumber` and good riddance to all this, but my curiosity urges me not to turn a blind eye on it.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you scheduling the block operation in some operation queue or so when the block executes later in the future.

You should not assign `self` to `weakSelf` inside the block. You should do this outside the block

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
if(weakSelf->_flag)
```

> __weak specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive. A weak reference is set to nil when there are no strong references to the object.
>   [Apple arc docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You actually want your `weakSelf` be not null to do some stuff with it. To do so you must declare assign it to a variable with strong ownership qualifier.
Sketch:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
schedule_block(^{
// at this point the object pointed by weakSelf may or may not be deallocated
id strongSelf = self; // after this point the object referenced by `strongSelf` will not be deallocated at least `strongSelf` to the end of current block
//You may safely work with `strongSelf` and be sure the object will live at least to the end of current block
});
```

To sum up: to be sure the object will not be deallocated while you work with it you should obtain a strong reference to it. On the other hand to prevent memory leaks you should use weak references. The algorithm looks like this:

1. obtain weak reference to object of interest
2. schedule block
3. at the start of block obtain a strong reference

   1. if object still live - do whatever you need
   2. if object was deallocated earlier - skip operations in block

---

iVar is just a member of C-structure the compiler creates for the class at compile time. All references to ivars will be compiled to `self-><ivar_name>`.

You may refer to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) for details or to [LLVM specs on ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) or [LLVM specs on blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html)

Comment: Thanks, I understand why we need to use weak within blocks. The question is more about why would there be warning when I use `__weak` and then needing to cast back to `__strong` to access the `BOOL` (this step seems superfluous to me: because I would then be using again a strong reference). Another part is about when `BOOL` is declared not as a property but still I need to use a `__weak` reference before it, when normally we don’t even need to use „self“ to access an ivar (i.e. `flag` instead of `self.flag` because it is not declared as property).

Comment: I believe it is a precaution. Imagine a block that use `weakSelf` 10 times. You do not know and can't be sure when the object referenced by `weakSelf` will be deallocated. That is why you should obtain `__storng` reference. To keep the object live as long as you need it.

Comment: About properties and ivars: first of all the property declaration just declares ivar and accessor methods. The ivars are compiled as members of C-structure that represents Objective-C class. The only way you can access ivar is to use `self` pointer: `self-><ivar_name>`. All ivar references in code (whether ivar itself an object or a plain int, BOOL or float) are compiled to `self-><ivar_name>`. Here you can see implicit usage of `self`.

Comment: Allow me some time to go through this thoroughly. Thanks. +1 for code examples and relevant docs.

Comment: My above comments is not correct for 100%. You should take into account that calling the property obj.property is just a message sending to in objective-c [obj property] which is safe in case if obj is nil. Objective-C allows this. But if you using ivar there is error at pure-C level - dereferencing NULL is always an error. To sum up: you may safely send messages and read properties on __weak references but you can't access ivars because there is a possibility this this variable will be nulled-out. –

Answer (score 0):

You start with a weak pointer to an object. The object can disappear at any time, setting the weak pointer to nil. Once you assign it to a strong pointer, the strong pointer may have been set to nil if the weak pointer was nil at the time, but once it is set to non-nil, it stays non-nil because it holds a reference keeping the object alive.

```
if (strongSelf->_flag)
```

is dangerous, because strongSelf could be nil, leading to a crash.

```
if (strongSelf != nil && strongSelf->_flag)
```

is safe because the flag will not be tested unless strongSelf is not nil.

```
if (weakSelf->_flag)
```

is obviously also dangerous. But perhaps surprising is that

```
if (weakSelf != nil && weakSelf->_flag)
```

is also dangerous, because just because weakSelf was not nil when you checked it, doesn't mean it's not nil a nanosecond later when you try to access _flag.

Comment: It seems like the last example `if (weakSelf != nil && weakSelf->_flag)` is safe because according to [LLVM ARC Specs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics)(read semantics) objects with `weak` storage qialifiers are kept alive till end of expression. Basically it will be retained before `weakSelf != nil && weakSelf->_flag` evaluation and will be released at the point when expression value evaluated.

Comment: My above comment is true and false at the same time. True: `__weak` references retained before expression evaluation. False: the code won't compile becase of `weakSelf->_flag`. compiler do not allow code that dereferences `__weak` pointers because it may lead to dereferencing NULL which is error. In pure-C world you are responsible for all NULL-checks and compiler do not care what pointers you dereferencing. But with ARC you sharing this responsibility and due to `__weak` modifier compiler knows that this variable may be accidentally nulled-out.

Comment: @MaxK: the argument about it being NULL is the same for `__strong`, but the compiler allows using `->` on that.

Comment: With `__strong` the compiler acts as in pure-C world - the reference cannot be nulled out accidentally, only you in your code may explicitly null it out. But there is a danger with `__weak` - it may be nulled out accidentally, implicitly. It is stated in the error message: `Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed due to possible null value caused by race condition, assign it to strong variable first`. The `__weak` pointer may be nulled out because the object you referencing may be deallocated somewhere in another thread.

Comment: Please take a look at my above [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592108/accessing-bool-within-blocks/22592942?noredirect=1#comment34489197_22592414).